# Does a parent bash script remember the cd history from a child bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, cd-command

Example:

mainscript.sh

```
cd /mnt/something
./buildscripts/000-script.sh
```

000-script.sh

```
cd /mnt/otherthing
mkdir something
exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the executed process will **not** change the working directory of the parent process.

Example:

- caller.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo -n "Caller 1 " ; pwd
  ./callee.sh
  echo -n "Caller 2 " ; pwd
  ```
- callee.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo -n "Callee 1 " ; pwd
  cd /tmp
  echo -n "Callee 2 " ; pwd
  exit
  ```

Calling `caller.sh` will produce

```
Caller 1 /Users/corti/tmp
Callee 1 /Users/corti/tmp
Callee 2 /tmp
Caller 2 /Users/corti/tmp
```

As you see when printing `Caller 2` the parent process has still the same working directory

Answer (score 0):

The "child" is not remembering anything. This is just a basic concept that processes are started from their current working directory (cwd). If you look at /proc/* on a Linux-system you can see that entry for every process.